# Grid date column js error

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, javascript, grid, date

I added a date type column in a custom grid.

```
$this->addColumn('some_date', array(
    'header'=> Mage::helper('helper_alias')->__('Some Date'),
    'index' => 'some_date',
    'type'=> 'date',
));
```

Now, when I try to filter my grid by that value and click on the calendar icon I get a js error.

> TypeError: $(...) is null

The line that is causing this is

```
var index = $("widget-chooser").getStyle("zIndex");
```

because `$("widget-chooser")` is `null`.

If I change the column type to `datetime` the error does not appear. (but I don't want `datetime` I want `date`).

The problem reproduces in the core grids (Shopping cart promo rules for example).

Is there anyway to avoid this?

Comment: In you case "widget-chooser" is class or id of an DOM element?

Comment: @Tim. In my case I have no idea what"widget-chooser" is. I have no code related to anything names "widget" or "chooser". I'm starting to think this is a bug. I'm digging deeper.

Comment: Checked. It's a valid ID. Do you have `js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/widget.js` loaded?

Comment: I didn't tell Magento to load widget.js. And I don't need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a deep investigation, the results are in.
*This is definitely a bug.*
The code in question

```
var index = $("widget-chooser").getStyle("zIndex");
```

Was added in 1.4, to fix a bug. Apparently, when you had a date element in a widget configuration screen, the calendar was appearing below the element with the widget configuration and you couldn't select a date.

The code is there in order to set a `z-index` to the calendar element bigger than the `z-index` of the widget element.

I tried to avoid class rewrites, so here is my stupid fix to the issue:
I created a custom layout handle in one of the admin layout files.

```
<fix_calendar_js_issue>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/text" name="dummy-widget-chooser" as="dummy-widget-chooser">
            <action method="setText">
                <text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript">
                    Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
                        if (!$('widget-chooser')) {
                            $$('body')[0].insert('<div id="widget-chooser"></div>');
                        }
                });
                </script>]]></text>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</fix_calendar_js_issue>
```

This just ads a div with id `widget-chooser` if one does not exist in the DOM.

Now all I have to do is to include this handle in the pages that show this error.
For example the shopping cart price rules.

```
<adminhtml_promo_quote_index>
    <update handle="fix_calendar_js_issue" />
</adminhtml_promo_quote_index>
```

All of these can be done from a single custom layout file.

Comment: I like your stupid fix. Non-intrusive all the way.

Comment: it is non-intrusive but I'm not 100% sure that there are no side effects to it.

Answer (score 2):

I can replicate this on a vanilla 1.7 install. I wonder how this got unnoticed.

Anyway, the problem is in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Filter_Date::getHtml()`. At the end of the JS string, additional callbacks are bound to the click event. Removing those (via anything-except-directly-from-core; you know the drill) fixes your problem. I'm talking about these lines [>>here<<](https://github.com/mageplus/mageplus/blob/master/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Filter/Date.php#L78-L99).

Two reasons why I think that's erroneous legacy code:

- the "widget-chooser" ID is dinamically created with `WysiwygWidget.chooser.openDialogWindow` in `js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/widget.js` (code [here](https://github.com/mageplus/mageplus/blob/master/js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/widget.js#L374)), and this `openDialogWindow` is used in *other* places than the date picker (I don't know exactly which are those, but it's related to `Mage_Widget_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Chooser`)
- `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Filter_Datetime` [doesn't have those extra callbacks](https://github.com/mageplus/mageplus/blob/master/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Filter/Datetime.php#L142), and this class is the direct child of `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Filter_Date`.

Of course, I may be wrong.

Comment: I was looking in the same place. I seams thay you don't even need to remove those lines, If I replace `var index = $("widget-chooser").getStyle("zIndex");` with `var index = ($("widget-chooser")) ? $("widget-chooser").getStyle("zIndex") : 0;` seams to solve it but I don't want to edit the core (duh!). I think someone assumes that there is always going to be an element with id `widget-chooser` in the DOM. Definatelly a bug by my book.

Comment: Still, I wonder why they bound other click events, when `Calendar.setup` already does that. They seem to tackle multiple calendar overlapping? Moving the dialog into the browser viewport? And, yes, I think they assume `widget-chooser`'s existence. Maybe they used `WysiwygWidget.chooser.openDialogWindow` for the calendar in 0.0.1.